# CSS Horizontal image alignment with image titles

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

Our organization works in a content management system and for expedited reasons we've arranged pictures using tables.  I'd like to get away from that practice and provide a road map (CSS) to doing it properly.

We arrange pictures in a row side-by-side with a title under the picture, normally two lines of text.

Here is an example of what I start constructing.

```
<style>

 #piccaption
 {
font-size: x-small;
 }

 #picimages
 {
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px auto; 
 }

#picimages a
{
margin:0px 0px;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}

</style>
```

Using this with my HTML...

```
<div id="picimages">
<img alt="Picture ALT" src="http://webaddress.com/picture.jpg" width="140px" height="203px" />
<div id="piccaption"><span>Picture Caption</span><br />
<span>Second Line</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with the proper way to do this as well as place a 2nd, 3rd picture next to this first one with a nice padding between the pictures?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to lay multiple blocks out horizontally would be to set the display to inline-block, with margins on either side to space them the way you like. Inline-block works in all browsers from Internet Explorer 8 and up (if you really need to make it compatible with Internet Explorer 7, you can add `*display: inline` after the inline-block).

The advantage of using inline-block instead of floats is that even if an image has an exceptionally long caption, the layout doesn't break as it would with floats.

Also, be sure to use classes instead of IDs for elements that occur more than once on a page.

Here is a jsFiddle example based on the code you pasted: http://jsfiddle.net/skymaiden/zvpHW/

Comment: You completely ROCK.  Thank you...  Would it be too much to ask for a solution that wrapped the second set of images onto their own line below the first?

Comment: All you need to do is put a `<div>` around the images you want to group. Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/skymaiden/M5M9j/](http://jsfiddle.net/skymaiden/M5M9j/)